# Understanding this part arm assembly code

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, cortex-m

```
.syntax unified
.thumb

.cpu cortex-m4
.arch armv7e-m
.fpu fpv4-sp-d16

/* Changes from unprivileged to privileged mode. */
.thumb_func
.section    .kernel
.global     raise_privilege
.type       raise_privilege, %function
raise_privilege:
mrs     r0, control
bic     r0, r0, #1
msr     control, r0
dsb
isb
bx      lr
```

this is part of arm assembly code. I can check chip manual to figure out the meaning of the instructions. But I don't know how to figure out the behavior of assembler directives like `.thumb_func`. What's more, I also don't know how to use this part code, it doesn't' look like regular function. So I don't know how to "call" it.

Comment: The pseudo ops are probably irrelevant to figuring out **what** the code does.  See [contrl register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/CHDBIBGJ.html), which is not *ARM*, but *cortex-M* specific.  Thumb inter-networking is probably not too useful, nor is `unified` for a *cortex-M*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The *instructions* starting with a `.` are really assembler directives. You can look them up in [GAS: ARM machine directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html)
- `.syntax unified` signals the use of unified ARM / Thumb assembly syntax. The concept is explained [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/i/Cjagjjbc) and [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet.html#ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet).
- `.thumb_func` signals the start of a Thumb mode function for ARM-Thumb interwork. The concept is explained [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/i/Bcghfebi) and [here](http://twins.ee.nctu.edu.tw/courses/ip_core_01/lab_hw_pdf/lab_1.pdf).
- `raise_privilege` looks exactly like a `void raise_privilege(void)` *leaf function* (i.e. it doesn't call other functions) in C to me. Call it with:

```
bl raise_privilege
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu assembler is broken, goofy, awkward, choose your word...

in this case .thumb_func plus a label is all you need in order to be able to call that label the thumb_func tells the assembler the following label is something I may want to call or load the address and use bx.

so in this code or other you can simply

```
bl raise_priviliedge
```

(if the bl can reach and/or the linker adds the trampoline).  or you can

```
ldr rX,=raise_priviledge  
blx rX
```

where rX is some general purpose register (r3 for example).